# How to handle this closed question that I believe has useful info but is in the wrong format?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

A couple of years ago I asked my first question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976027/how-to-remove-cprog-windows-mobile-phone-app. It was actually not a question, but the answer to a big problem that I thought lots of people had tried to solve, and I really thought that this might help someone. It was correctly closed and I have just let it be ever since. But now I wonder what to do with it. Should I just let it be deleted and disappear? Or should I myself delete it and ask the question again, adding my own answer to it?

Comment: Just leave it- it's not hurting anyone, and it will probably eventually get culled as an old closed question.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is possible. But that question can be flagged to the moderator to migrate to  http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/, if it is worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the WindowsPhone.SE community well enough to say where it is or isn't on topic there, but since multiple people have suggested that site, it is definitely worth considering.

But if you repost, just remember that it is a Q&A site, so make sure the question is formatted as a good question, and the answer is a good answer.  Unfortunately self-answered questions tend to be judged more harshly.  Don't just make the question "How to Remove Cprog".  Try to include more detail to make it a real question, otherwise you run the risk of downvoting or getting closed on the new site as well, even if the answer is good.

Comment: Ok, good suggestion, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Post your question to https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/